# make margin scale with respect to height rather than width

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/NykbP/

I am trying to make my margin-bottom css properties on `.header`, `.mainBanner`, and the `li`s scale relative to the height of the document/window but they are scaling relative to the width of the document/window while the heights of the `div`s are scaling properly...

```
height:8%
```

The above scales correctly

```
margin-bottom:2%;
```

The above does not.

How can I make them scale relative to the height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Margin declared in percentages is based on its parent node's width.  Go figure.

Here's a great article that should help you out: http://mattsnider.com/css-using-percent-for-margin-and-padding/

Comment: Is there any way I could use position relative and the positioning properties to simulate margins as they are positioned with respect to height and not width?

Comment: Yes.  You can also use javascript and quickly generate margins in percentages.  Get the window height, subtract the height of the containers, and whatever is left over, apply as margins.  Put it in a function, and run it on document load, and bind it to the window.resize event and you're golden.